# grep -f producing false matches

Tags: grep

Completely dumbfounded with this, using -

```
grep -f list.txt c:/texts/*.txt > output
```

list.txt contains a list of strings to grep

C:/texts/*.txt contains a bunch of text files to search

for some strong reason it keeps outputting false matches, or the entire file regardless of match I'm not sure, but example

```
list.txt contains >

user1@hotmail.com
```

C:/text/ contains

```
firstsearch.txt contains >

usernoname@hotmail.com:phonenumber:location
```

and it will output that as a match :S.. makes no sense, or I'm just missing the obvious, i don't know?

Comment: Make sure that there are no empty lines in the `list.txt` pattern file.  An empty line in the pattern file will match every line in the searched files.

Comment: @ottomeister thanks didn't realise empty lines would produce entire searched file, you've saved a lot of stress! :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grep -Ff producing invalid output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48132274/grep-ff-producing-invalid-output)