# grep -Ff producing invalid output

Tags: bash, awk, grep, gawk, gnuwin32

I'm using

code -

```
 grep -Ff list.txt C:/data/*.txt > found.txt
```

but it keeps outputting invalid responses, lines don't contain the emails i input..

list.txt contains -

```
email@email.com
customer@email.com
imadmin@gmail.com
newcustomer@email.com
helloworld@yes.com
```

and so on.. email to match on each line,

search files contain -

```
user1:phonenumber1:email@email.com:last-active:recent
user2:phonennumber2:customer@email.com:last-active:inactive
user3:phonenumber3:blablarandom@bla.com:last-active:never
```

then another may contain -

```
blublublu         email@email.com         phonenumber         subscribed
nanananana        customer@email.com      phonenumber         unsubscribed
useruser          noemailinput@noemail.com       phonenumber      pending
```

so what I'm trying to do is present grep with a list of emails/list of strings " list.txt " and to then search the directory provided for matches of each string and output the entire line that contains each match.

example of output in this case would be -

```
user1:phonenumber1:email@email.com:last-active:recent
user2:phonennumber2:customer@email.com:last-active:inactive
blublublu         email@email.com         phonenumber         subscribed
nanananana        customer@email.com      phonenumber         unsubscribed
```

yet it wouldn't output the other two lines -

```
 user3:phonenumber3:blablarandom@bla.com:last-active:never
 useruser          noemailinput@noemail.com       phonenumber      pending
```

because no string is within that line.

Comment: I copied the contents to files and ran the command. It didn't output the user3 and noemailinput.

Comment: [Déjà vu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48123320/3776858)?

Comment: @Cyrus solution didn't work & it doesn't seem to be working for me guys :S

Comment: @choroba try an email with like special characters " -, _, . " or something like that, maybe that's what is causing my issue?

Comment: Upload list.txt somewhere and add link here.

Comment: https://www.sendspace.com/file/snmf4m

Comment: I suggest `dos2unix s.txt` to remove DOS linefeeds.

Answer (score 0):

I think your file `list.txt` may have blank lines in it, causing it to match every line in the files specified with `C:/data/*.txt`. To fix you can either manually delete every empty line or run the command `sed -i '/^$/d' list.txt` where the `-i` flag edits the file in place.

The issue may also be related to dos carriage returns, try running: `cat -v list.txt` and checking if the lines are followed by `^M`:

```
email@email.com^M
customer@email.com^M
```

If this is the case you will need to amend the file using either `dos2unix` or `tr -d '\r' < list.txt > output.txt`.

Comment: it's still producing unmatched lines, is it possible that the files being searched are causing the issue? OR potentially special characters? so like " . ", " - ", "_" etc

Comment: I don't think grep has an issue with them and I can only seem to recreate your issue if I have empty lines. Maybe you could try using `grep -wFf`?

Comment: I just tried with my examples above and works fine, but for the actual content I want to match with it produces false lines.. :S is it possibly caused by the content I'm searching?

Comment: Added an additional comment about special characters, hope it fixes your issue.

Comment: @jakereading how are we supposed to help you debug a problem that doesn't exist with the sample input you provided? Wouldn't it make sense when posting sample input/output to provide data that **does** reproduce your problem rather than data that **doesn't** reproduce it? "My car won't start, please take a look at this bicycle and tell me what's wrong".

Answer (score 0):

The file `list.txt` probably contains empty lines **or some of the separators**. When I added `:` to list.txt, all the lines from the first sample started to match. Similarly, adding a space made all the lines from the second sample match. Adding `@` causes the same symptoms.

Try running `grep -oFf ...` (if your grep supports `-o`) to see the exact matching parts. If there are empty lines in list.txt, the number of matches will be less than the number of matches without `-o`. Try searching the output of `-o` for extremely short outputs to check for suspicious strings. You can also examine the shortest lines in list.txt.

```
while read line ; do echo ${#line} "$line" ; done < list.txt | sort -nk1,1
```

Comment: strange thing is if I use -o it only outputs matches but not full line, just the emails it found from my list

Comment: Yes, that's what `-o` does.

Comment: so why when I remove -o it outputs false matches :s

Comment: For me, it only happens when I have empty lines in the list.